# How to capture system alarm events in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to capture a broadcast from any system level alarm which I set using the clock application. My scenario is that if I am watching a video, and if any alarm comes in, the video should stop. For this, I need some broadcast of the alarm so that I can stop my video.

The below code is if I am setting an alarm in my application. I will get it in my broadcast. My question is how to capture the alarms set via the clock app?
I have seen the Youtube and VLC app do it. They stop the video if any alarm is triggered and play the video again if the alarm is snoozed or dismissed.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
    + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);
```